# "No logs" in Switzerland and Internet crime

Tags: internet, switzerland

ProtonVPN says that their servers are in Switzerland and that:

> Under Swiss law, we are not obligated to save any user connection logs, nor can we be forced to perform targeted logging on specific users. This allows us to ensure that your private browsing history does in fact stay private and cannot be turned over to a third party under any circumstances.

How come this is viable? What if people use their service to commit crimes?

Comment: "No logs" in the context of VPN [does not cover the ass](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194394/is-this-a-viable-defense-against-correlation-attacks) of anyone who risks to use it to commit crimes. It just makes it harder to trace them. So treat "No logs" just as marketing feature of the VPN provider.

Comment: Please be aware that, even if a VPN does not keep logs, the ISP they use (which they have no control over) absolutely will, and it will be able to deanonymize someone using the VPN via trivial [traffic analysis](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/175179/165253).

Comment: What do you mean by “viable”?

Answer (score 6):

> How come this is viable?

Because it’s legal.

> What if people use their service to commit crimes?

What if people use a Ford in a bank holdup? Or a Glock in a murder? Or the US Postal Service in a Nigerian letter scam?

If the goods or services are legal and not provided for an obviously illegal purpose, nothing happens.

Comment: This is contrary to a service like Napster whose purpose was found to be primarily illegal.