# GDPR: Do I have to IP log "every" login for a customer?

Tags: gdpr

IP addresses are personal data according to GDPR as far as I know. Whenever customer registers, I log IP address, timestamp, other details which are given by the customer such as name, address etc. After that, when customer logs in again with the same IP address, do I have to log that login with new timestamp?
If I don't log every login and when customer asks for GDPR data, I will only be able to provide IP addresses he/she was having with only one timestamp, not subsequent logins' timestamps.
Is this a good implementation or wrong/inadequate in terms of regulation/law?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The intention of the GDPR is to **minimize** the amount of personally identifiable information (PII) you store. So the GDPR never tells you that you *have* to log certain events. The simplest way to make sure you comply with the GDPR is to simply not store any PII at all. But that might of course conflict with legitimate business interests and with other legal obligations you might have. So when you *do* store PII, then the GDPR regulates under which conditions you are *allowed* to store PII, for how long and what you are allowed to do with that PII.

So when you receive a GDPR request from a customer to see their data, then you can say that you only have that one timestamp of their registration, because you didn't log their subsequent logins (assuming this is the truth).

I hope your privacy policy says that you store all that PII on registration and that you have some good arguments why storing that information is a "legitimate interest" of your organization.

Comment: We log the IP address of all logins; this is used when somebody complains "not me" and we need to find out where it came from. I can't imagine the alternative being a good idea.

Comment: @Joshua you still need a written policy of how long is reasonable to keep it. And "indefinitely" is not a legal option.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Any other choice but indefinitely results in a conflict with US law. The logs are not supposed to be re-writable (this is buried deep in the HIPAA law and I'd rather it wasn't so but it is so. It's the direct consequence of the non-tamperability requirement.)

Comment: @Joshua: HIPAA allows you to discard logs entirely, right? The "non-modification" means you can't rewrite the 1975 logs to keep record type A but discard record type B. However, if you group your log data by expiry date, you don't need to alter the data. Regardless, a conflict between US law and GDPR just means you need two independent systems. Neither has an exception for the other. (The GDPR _does_ recognize equivalent protection levels, but the US of course falls far short of that level)

Comment: @MSalters: It also means the US system housing US records needs to keep the login logs for a stupid long time even though the IP addresses are definitely EU IP addresses. We've had debates as to how long we have to keep the logs but even the lowest interpretation is so long that the first log entry hasn't expired yet.

Comment: Also, one of the interpretations is the logs need to be written to WORM media. This also means the records can't be discarded until the newest record on that WORM is ready to be discarded.

Comment: @Joshua - IP address is not necessarily a good identifier for "not me".  For residential users IP can change relatively regularly.  Geographic lookup can be wildly wrong, even before factoring in use of VPNs .... or someone on vacation.... You'd be better off mandating true two-factor authentication.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: What is the ultimate end of two factor? Everything wants to use some other service as the second factor. Something has to be the root that everything else stands on.

Comment: @Joshua _if_ HIPAA applies to IP addresses of logins, then you are still not required to keep them indefinitely, especially after the subject has died.

Comment: @Joshua the ultimate end of two-factor is having multiple separate requirements for authentication. The whole point is that there isn't a single root to stand on.

Comment: @Joshua Regarding the interaction between GDPR and HIPPA, you also need to be aware of the interaction with the Patriot act if you want to have a US System storing EU data in a fully compliant manner. Look into the history of Schrems I and Schrems II and the trans-Atlantic Data Privacy Framework. You need at least some flexibility in interpretation or completely partitioned systems.

Comment: @Joshua - More specifically, you want the second factor to be something that _they physically possess_.  Usually, this is a phone with an authenticator application, although dedicated devices like FIDO keys are becoming more common.  You don't want this to be a "second service" login, like sending an email or text message, if you can avoid it (although these can be spoofed or intercepted, that's usually a high bar for most attacks.  Rather, you just don't want to rely on such a remote service at all).  It makes it much harder for people to say "not me" in such cases.

Comment: @user1937198: The only way to get US system to store EU data is to try to log into the US system as an EU resident.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: My bank wants to use text message or email. My email provider wants to use text message or phone app. My phone provider wants to use email. Nobody wants to use TLS keys. Nobody wants to use physical tokens, and the few that offer it don't have a good plan for when they fail. I am fed up with this nonsense.

Comment: @OrangeDog: There is no feasible technological implementation of the set of all the HIPAA requirements that contains within it any form of selective delete other than "this record and all prior records". Should the case appear on the board requiring selective destruction we will have to ask a judge to invalidate one of the requirements.

Comment: @Joshua you seem to be largely misunderstanding both the law, and what everyone is trying to explain

Answer (score 13):

GDPR means that **if** you handle personal data, **then** you need proper procedures and a valid reason for doing so. Customer consent is one valid reason, but not the only one.

- Do you have a technical or business reason to preserve records of every login, including the IP? If not, just don't do it. Data without a good purpose is just a headache for you.
- If you want to log every login (a bank might do so, I guess ...), decide what your reason is. Is it *necessary* to fulfill a contract? Then the contract is your reason. You have to document that and explain it in your legal boilerplate. But if you want to collect data for better targeted advertising, you probably need the consent of the data subject.
- If you have a valid reason, you also need to decide *how long* the data must be stored, and implement data access procedures, etc.

If you have *customers,* then you are a business, and you should hire an expert to advise you. You might be required to appoint a Data Protection Officer for your company, too.

Comment: I don't have a technical/business reason to preserve records of every login. I don't like loads of data lying in my database for no reason of course. But what if a law enforcement officer asks for a specific login and I couldn't provide that, will this officer tell me this is against law? I suppose I won't have a problem since I don't handle multiple login records. Am I right? (sorry if I ask too much or it is silly, forgive me.)

Comment: @cagatay117 GDPR does not really interact with such requirements. *If* there is such a EU/EU member/UK law that requires retaining user IP addresses, GDPR allows you to fulfil that obligation. But GDPR itself doesn't require data processing (see also Art 11, though there can be difficulties in connection with Art 7(1) records of consent). Also note that data retention laws that require blanket retention without concrete suspicion have been repeatedly ruled to violate EU law.

Comment: @cagatay117, your documentation requirements will vary depending on your sector of industry, and details also vary from country to country.

Comment: @cagatay117 `But what if a law enforcement officer asks for a specific login and I couldn't provide that, will this officer tell me this is against law?` this is a big speculation on your part. Some businesses do not require logs, and if LEO asks you for information, it may or may not be viable to just not have it ready, depending on the regulations. See e.g. (claimed) "no-log" VPNs https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/34328/no-logs-in-switzerland-and-internet-crime.

Comment: @Lodinn: That's why you really should have that GDPR documentation of the data you store. LEO arrives, you give him the breakdown of what you store and why, and the LEO can then decide to get a court order. But the court can obviously only pick from the list you provide.

Comment: Data without good reason is not a headache, it is illegal.  GDPR states that you MUST NOT retain data that you do not need.

Comment: @TomV, there is always data with flimsy excuses. Scoundrels use their legitimate interest in stable operations to backup anything and everything ...

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, GDPR does not require you to collect any data; in contrary - data minimization principle requires one to use as little as possible data. But when you use data you need to have a valid purpose (why you use data? what you want to achieve?) and legal grounds (for example - consent or your legitimate interest in e.g. ensure security of your site).
There are though requirements in GDPR like to ensure proof of collecting consent or ensuring security of data processing (all activities related to data on individual). That's where collecting of IP may be needed.
From your question, however, it seems that you do not know why you are registering IP addresses and how would you use them. So my suggestion is to stop collecting them until you define the specific need and way you will use them.